# Record Audio for Android and iOS using Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I'm having problems trying to record audio into a file. I'm trying to run the sample code (with the required permissions in the tiapp.xml) but i'm always getting errors (like  "+[NSBlock boundBridge:withKrollObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1b5549500"; at the stop() action).

I can't find a module for audio recording (i've used the tutorial.audiorecord but it doesn't work in newest versions of SDK)

This is the sample code from the appcelerator documentation page https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.AudioRecorder

I try everything but doesn't work.

Someone have a working example or a module for Appcelerator SDK 7?

```js
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: '#fff'
});

var recordStart = Ti.UI.createButton({
  title: 'Start',
  top: 10
});

var recordPause = Ti.UI.createButton({
  title: 'Pause',
  top: 60
});

var recordStop = Ti.UI.createButton({
  title: 'Stop',
  top: 110
});

var recordPlay = Ti.UI.createButton({
  title: 'Play',
  top: 160
});

var audioRecorder = Ti.Media.createAudioRecorder();

var record;
var audioPlayer;

window.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
  if (!Ti.Media.hasAudioRecorderPermissions()) {
    Ti.Media.requestAudioRecorderPermissions(function(e) {
      if (e.success) {
        window.add(recordStart);
      }
    });
  } else {
    window.add(recordStart);
  }
});

recordStart.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  audioRecorder.start();
});

recordPause.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (audioRecorder.getPaused()) {
    recordPause.setTitle('Pause');
    audioRecorder.resume();
  } else {
    recordPause.setTitle('Resume');
    audioRecorder.pause();
  }
});

recordStop.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  record = audioRecorder.stop();
  Ti.API.info(record.getNativePath());
});

recordPlay.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  audioPlayer = Ti.Media.createAudioPlayer({
    url: record.getNativePath()
  });
  audioPlayer.start();
});

window.add(recordPause);
window.add(recordStop);
window.add(recordPlay);

window.open();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend you use hyperloop and use Android's MediaRecorder, basically you would only need to translate this example to JS https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using Titanium's Hyperloop: https://gist.github.com/dinahgarcia/119ac00c91334d3951601cf347bad8d4
To be able to use it you need to enable Hyperloop: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Enabling_Hyperloop